# Wordpress User Role Accessibilities

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress, how to create a new user role that can only access the 'donation' sidebar function as the image below? Please help...[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyp93.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes yes it is possible to do this.
You need to select the user role "Give Accountant" for the concerned user in the WordPress backoffice "Accounts" -> "All Accounts" -> Select the user and change his status.

Then you have to add these PHP instructions in your child theme

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'restrict_screen' );

 function restrict_screen() {
    if (current_user_can('give_accountant')) {
               if( preg_match('/\bindex\.php\b|\bprofile\.php\b|\bwp-admin.?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
                $current_admin = get_admin_url() .'edit.php?post_type=give_forms';
                header('Location: ' . $current_admin . '', true, 301);
                }
        }
 }

add_action('admin_init', 'disable_dashboard');
function disable_dashboard() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return null;
    }
        
    if (current_user_can('give_accountant')) {
         remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );
         remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For user **role capabilities** you can also use the **plugin**.
Here I have shared the plugin which I like.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

I know it is a little bit longer but it is a very good plugin if in the future any changes in the requirement then the plugin will very helpful.

Here you can set the settings according to your **requirement**.